# Is Shapiro-Wilks a good test for a small data set with ties?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I'm working with the residuals of 1000 parts, which were forecasted per month for 12 months.  Therefore, each part consists of 12 residual values.  Since some are also based on intermittent data (lots of zeros and tied values), is there a statistical test I can use over all parts to confirm those that show normality and those that don't.

I'm using R.  Is Royston's Extended SW method implemented in R?

Comment: Could you please say more about why you need to test for normality? It's also not completely clear what you mean by "parts" in this context.

Comment: 1. If you have ties, it isn't actually normal. 2. The fact that there are "lots of zeros" means there's no point whatever in even considering normality - it's plainly not normal. 3. There is no way to "confirm those that show normality". Failure to reject normality isn't the same thing as having normality.

Comment: The data represents the residuals (demand (requirement) my forecast (actual orders)) of an inventory of parts.  There are 1000 parts in the inventory and the system uses Croston's method for intermittent demand (plenty of zeros), Moving average, SES and DES depending on which forecast gives the smallest error.  I'm just testing the residuals for normality, and while I agree that those with zeros and ties will be hard-pressed to achieve normality, out of 1000 parts this is not always the case.  I was thinking about Shapiro-Wiilk Extended, but unsure if it's available in R.